# How to add data to file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, overriding, using, activexobject

I want to make registration form and write the data into data.txt using ActiveXObject.
What I write is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function WriteFile()
    {
       var fso  = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
       var fh = fso.CreateTextFile("E:\\Test.txt", true);
       x=document.getElementById("name").value;
       y=document.getElementById("password").value;
       fh.WriteLine(x+"#"+y);
       fh.Close();
    }
</script>
<BODY>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="name"/>
    <input type="text" id="password"/>
    <input type="button" value="Sign Up" id="write" onclick="WriteFile()"/>
</form>
</BODY>
```

When I tried that way, every time I click Sign Up button, the new data override the previous data. I tried to use `fh.AppendLine(x + "#" + y)` but it didn't work.

Could anyone help me how to add data, not override data?

Comment: That's only possible in IE in a trusted zone, why do you want to write to a file?

Comment: Why are you doing that? You know that it will only work in IE right?

Comment: Yap, it only works in IE.
It's my college's tasks, so I have to do it that way..
Anyone know how to add data not override it?

Comment: @greenthunder can you tell me what college is that so I can stop anyone I know from attending ever?

Comment: @Xeon06 I've gone web class. so they taught me from basic (like vbscript, javascript, activeX) then next is advance (php, jsp)

Comment: @greenthunder I understand, but as a college teacher myself, I don't think *anyone* should ever teach VBScript ever.

Comment: @Xeon06 So all classic ASP is irrelevant and all legacy systems should be disregarded?

Comment: @user1090190 Yes, haha. But let me rephrase. I don't think anyone should ever teach *client-side* VBScript. Ever.

Comment: @Xeon06 I mean, in all fairness, client sided VBscript is very very close to server side VBscript and it is far easier to use client sided VBscript than to configure a classic ASP server on any computer you want to develop on. ;p

Comment: @user1090190 yes, that is true. But I don't think it gives students the right kind of experience and concepts, especially those starting out in web. At the very least, teach them JavaScript and PHP / ASP.NET first, and when they have a good understanding of it, you can show them VBScript. The fact that it is both used client-side and server-side can be very confusing for begginers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer** You should never use those functions. They only work in IE and are horrible.

I think your problem stems from using `CreateTextFile`. You should instead be using [`OpenTextFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) with the second parameter set to `8`. That will allow for appending.

Comment: thanks, it works. But, how if I want to write the data in new line? Should I write fh.WriteLine() for new Line first and then fh.WriteLine(x+"#"+y)? Or there's any syntax like '\n' in C?

Comment: @Xeon06 Ops, that's my mistake. It works, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

I've done stuff like this a long time ago... (when I was using windows) I think it is because you're replacing the file with a new file with `CreateTextFile` so if the file already exists you'll need to do this:

```
function AppendLine()
{
   var fso  = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
   var fh = fso.OpenTextFile("E:\\Training Asslab\\Advance\\Write to File\\Test.txt", 8, True);
   x=document.getElementById("name").value;
   y=document.getElementById("password").value;
   fh.WriteLine(x+"#"+y);
   fh.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CreateTextFile overrwrites the current file, I think.
You should use FileExists to check its presence before creating it.
If it does exist you can use OpenTextFile.

Here's the relevant [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use [OpenTextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method with create flag and ForAppending mode instead of `CreateTextFile`.

However, do understand, that you're not only limiting yourself to very old IE version and inside trusted zone, but you're also leaving files on user's local drives, not on your server. Because of that you can't do anything with this "registration data".